# Checking if scroll is at bottom in jquery in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, google-chrome

I have django project and I can't make jquery script to run in google chrome.

Simple code for checking if scroll is at bottom:

```
 <script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
    window.onload = function () {

       $('#scrolling').on('scroll', chk_scroll);
    };

    function chk_scroll(e) {

        var elem = $(e.currentTarget);
        if (elem[0].scrollHeight - elem.scrollTop() == elem.outerHeight()) {
           alert("bottom")
        }
    }
</script>
```

It works in Opera, Explorer, Firefox, Chrome (As single html file, not part of project), jsfiddle.

**P.s** jquery loads correctly and other scripts works.

Comment: Have you tried using [`$( document ).ready()`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) instead of `window.onload` once.

Comment: Yes, same result, as setTImeout

Comment: I don't necessarily think it is the issue, but the values in your language and type attributes are camelcased, when they should be lowercased.  Better yet, for normal script tags those can be left off.

Comment: Could this be any help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/28287574/7867822

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, learned new things and found problem. Anurag, your link really helped! It was in zooming browser with cntrl+scroll. My Chrome was zoomed by default to 105%, and this 5% was the problem.I simply need to count resizing

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```js
$( window ).on( 'scroll', checkScroll );


function checkScroll()
{
    const documentScrollTop     = $( document ).scrollTop();
    const documentOuterHeight   = $( document ).outerHeight();
    const windowOuterHeight     = $( window ).outerHeight();

    if ( documentScrollTop >= documentOuterHeight - windowOuterHeight )
    {
        //bottom
    }
}
```

you don't need to use any element but the window to check if you've hit bottom